# .htacces rewrite by cookie value

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, cookies, url-rewriting

I have a website in 2 languages. I'm inserting the text for each language through php constants and I define the user language through a cookie (`lang=es` or `lang=en`).
Now the base url in each language is `www.webname.com/` but i want to rewrite it depending on the language. If the cookie is set to `es` the url must be `www.webname.com/es/` and if it's in `en` must be `www.webname.com/en/`.
I'm looking in some manuals and tutorials but i'm really very bad with regular expressions.

EDIT:
I'm working on something like that in my .htaccess file:

`RewriteEngine On`
`RewriteCond %{HTTP_COOKIE} lang=en;? [NC]`

If I put a redirection like:
`RewriteRule ^ http://www.google.com [NC,L]` 
after it, it works but i don't know how to do the same with a rewrite.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this :

```
 RewriteEngine On 
 #Redirecting with the cookie value
 RewriteCond %{HTTP_COOKIE} ^lang=(en|es)$ [NC] 
 RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://example.com/%1/$1 [R,L]
```

If the cookie is set to "en" this will redirect every requests to 
    example.com/en/

Comment: I'm working with your code. I understand it and I assume that it has to work but it doesn't. Simply it doesn't rewrite anything in the URL.
I have deleted any other kind of code in the htaccess file just in case but it still isn't working.

Comment: Ok. I deleted the `^` of `^lang=(en|es)$` and it works now. Thank you.

Comment: Becareful with the `[NC]` flag which causes the RewriteRule to be matched in a case-insensitive manner. That is, it doesn't care whether letters appear as upper-case or lower-case in the matched URI.